# installation of android bundle

Tags: android

**after the installation, while android bundle fetch SDK its show the errror  like the below lines.**

Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Connection timed out: connect
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources

Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: Connect Connection timed out: connect
There is nothing to install or update.
The following SDK component was not installed: build-tools-21.1.1

**can anyone say the solve?**

Answer (score 0):

goto android SDK manager and install all the updates ,it solves the problem. If it is not updating check your network settings.